# What is the correct classification of population groups of homo sapiens?

Tags: human-biology

The classification system of the United States census into various races of humans is a bad way to classify population groups of humans, because both East Asians and South Asians are classified the same, yet they look different and are genetically distinct. So, has anyone proposed a more scientifically accurate classification of population groups of homo sapiens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically all the genetic variation of humans is inside the native african populations.  A norwegian and a australian native are more closely related  to each other than two random native Africans are. So the only accurate way to do it would not only group those two asians together but also group them with europeans and native americans. If you split people up enough to get two groups of "asians" then you end up with more than a hundred races the vast majority of whom would be split among the native african populations.

Humans have very low genetic diversity in the first place, and most of our diversity is within our populations not between them, so splitting us up does not make a lot of sense. We end up doing it mostly on superficial variations. 
[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15266342)