# Artifial insemination in milch varieties?

Tags: artificial-selection

Artificial insemination is used to produce offspring cows  and other milch varieties like buffaloes.. etc often use same sturdy males. Isn't it a step towards eugenics? What can be possible future harms?

Comment: Possible duplicates or related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/do-humans-have-enough-biological-differences-to-be-grouped-into-races-or-subspec https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66144/human-genetic-diversity-in-africa-in-comparison-with-the-rest-of-the-world

Comment: And what do you mean by "number dominance of Caucasians"?

Comment: "number dominance of Caucasians over other human divisions".... The phrasing is unclear but please note that there are ~1.3 billions Han Chinese and only ~0.85 billions caucasians.

Comment: [Does it make sense to classify all humans in a single species?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/does-it-make-sense-to-classify-all-humans-in-a-single-species) might also be a possible duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do humans have enough biological differences to be grouped into races or subspecies?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/do-humans-have-enough-biological-differences-to-be-grouped-into-races-or-subspec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no genetic basis for these classifications. Most human genetic diversity is in Africa. Diversity only decreases with geographic distance from this continent.  There are geographic clines, not the clusters that one might call race.  Here are some results from Rosenberg's 2002 Genetic Structure of Human Populations:

- 93-95% of variation occurs within populations
- 3-5% of variation occurs between populations

Local adaptation occurs, such as height and pigmentation but these phenotypes are polygenic and should not lead to binary classifications.  There are some very interesting case studies on local adaptation that you should look into. ex)EPAS1 gene and no hypoxia among Tibetans or lactose persistence on three continents

There is no genetic basis for dominance of one population over another.